# How to Terminate session in php when server displays error like forbidden error(403) or Not Found error(404)

Tags: php, mysql

I have developed a e-governance website using php and mysql which has been audited by a particular cyber company. In it's auditing stage they found one vulnerability in the web application. But i don't know how to solve it.They want me to destroy the user session(after login is performed and valid user is authenticated successfully), if any kind of server error comes up like forbidden Error or Not Found Error by typing malicious character in the authenticated URL and pressing enter after that. Please give me an idea. Below is the attached snippet pics of the auditing report. Please Check and Reply

[image]

.

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The answer would depend on: (1) How do you handle your URLs (apache rerwrite, a router of a framework or not at all)? (2) How do you handle the errors (any global error handling, redirect on exception ..)? (3) How do you handle user sessions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your sessions are linked to a database, but if they are not, then you could put the following code on the page when it returns an error:

```
<?php
// remove all session variables
session_unset(); 

// destroy the session 
session_destroy(); 
?>
```

Which would terminate the session

---

To call a function when an error is encountered you can use `set_error_handler(function);` and `register_shutdown_function(function);`

```
 function errorHandler() {
        if (error_get_last() and error_get_last()['type'] == '1') { //Optional - It depends on which errors you want to handle
            // remove all session variables
            session_unset(); 

            // destroy the session 
            session_destroy(); 

            // Provide a message to the user
            die("Error etc.");
        }
    }
    set_error_handler('errorHandler');
    register_shutdown_function('errorHandler');
```

You may need to change a few php.INI settings to get these functions to work, though the php docs and stack overflow will help you.

Comment: JBithell thnx for the answer but that i know how to destroy a user session..i mean ..i know the command..but i want to know what is the command in php to detect the server error code..i got one program in this particular link http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php . It is very complicated..i just want a specific code which will detect the server error code and then i will destroy the session accordingly. Please Reply again with proper and specific answer, SIr.

Comment: @RAHULDEB - I have updated my answer to include how to detect a server error if it is as a result of a PHP error. I hope you find my answer both proper and specific.

Comment: thnx a ton for the reply..will apply your logic in my application..If further any problem arises i may query you again...anewazz thnx again..Sir

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution would be to create custom error pages. The pages will have to be created by you in PHP and could simply destroy the session and redirect, or destroy the session and display some text that says the page doesn't exist.

This will have to be configured on the webserver to poing the errors to your pages (Apache, IIS). Your question does not provide information about the server hosting environment.

Comment: ckimbrell I am using wampserver 2.1e-x.It's Apache Version is 2.2.17 and php version is 5.3.5 and mysql version is 5.5.8. I got a web link where a small php program is written which used a global variable to detect server error code. But itz very complicated. I just want want to check which server error code comes up and destroy the user session from any authenticated page after any kind of malicious manipulation in the authenticated url. I want the proper specific php code to detect server error cod. Here's the link.- http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Comment: This links will provide you some info on creating a custom error page. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html If you point your page to a PHP file you have written, ex. ErrorDocument 404 /my404.php, you can customize the code in my404.php to destroy the user session, maybe then you forward them to index.php with no session data so they can start over.

Comment: Sir, problem has been solved by the custom error page logic..thnx for the help